# Is there a way to automatically generate identity row values in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, identity

In Sybase, I can designate a column of `NUMERIC` type as "IDENITY", and that column would automatically be populated with a numerical identity value that is unique when I insert the row (by Sybase, not inseting SQL).

Is there such a thing in SQLite 3?

I have seen "UNIQUEINDENTIFIER" type in SQLite Expert but that seems to expect a value when inserting a row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, you get an autoincrementing column by using the type [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).